# Creating a 3d plot from a data set?

Tags: python, matrix, 3d

Say for example I have:

```
x = arange(-5,5, .1)
y = arange(-5,5, .1)
```

and `z` is a data set corresponding to different values of `x` and `y`.

So `x` and `y` is are 1 x 100 arrays and `z` is a 100 x 100 matrix.

This is probably a very basic question but I'm struggling to get a 3d plot of `z` within the ranges of `x` and `y` in Python.

Answer (score 0):

Python doesn't support this out of the box, you'll need help from a graphics package.  The gold standard is [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/).

You can start by looking through the [3d plot gallery](http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html#mplot3d) and selecting the image that looks closest to what you want.